# Как отфильтровать массив объектов по нулевому значению

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов. Нужно исключить из объектов в нем все нулевые значения. То есть должны получить массив объектов. В каждом объекте только ключи с непутевыми значениями

Пример

```
  const arrOfObjects = [
    {a: null, b: "name", c: null, d: 100, e: "name"},
    {f: 1, g: null, h: 23, i: null, j: null},
    {k: null, l: "name", m: null, n: 100, o: "name"}
  ]

const result = [
    { b: "name",  d: 100, e: "name"},
    {f: 1,  h: 23,  ,
    {l: "name", n: 100, o: "name"}
]
```

вот мой код. как упростить?

```
const getFilterRows = rows => {
    return rows.map(obj =>
        Object.keys(obj)
            .filter(e => obj[e] !== null)
            .reduce((o, e) => {
                o[e] = obj[e];
                return o;
            }, {})
    );
};
```

Comment: Приведенный код работает?

Comment: да. но как его упростить. сделать более привлекательным что ли....

Comment: В чем измерять простоту и привлекательность?

Comment: можно ли как-то обойтись без reduce и чем-нибудь заменить?

Comment: reduce, как и map и filter - это обычный цикл, так что да, в итоге можно обойтись одним циклом по массиву и вторым по ключам объекта.

Answer (score 0):

Сами смотрите насколько это "проще" и "привлекательнее", но в любом случае это будет быстрее

Вам не нужен `filter`, ибо если Вы уже используете `reduce` то зачем дважды пробегать по массиву:

```js
const arrOfObjects = [
    {a: null, b: "name", c: null, d: 100, e: "name"},
    {f: 1, g: null, h: 23, i: null, j: null},
    {k: null, l: "name", m: null, n: 100, o: "name"}
]

const result = [
    { b: "name",  d: 100, e: "name"},
    {f: 1,  h: 23},
    {l: "name", n: 100, o: "name"}
]

const getFilterRows = rows => {
    return rows.map(obj =>
        Object.keys(obj)
            .reduce((prev, key) => (obj[key] !== null)? {...prev, [key]: obj[key]} : prev, {})
    );
};

const result2 = getFilterRows(arrOfObjects);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```